# Finding the right integral to calculate the area

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

i have the following question :

$R$ is an area that is confined  between the following :

$x=0$

$y=0$

$x+y=1$

$x+y=2$

I need to find the area for this trapezoid.

I thought of doing the following integral :

$$\int_1^2\int_{1-x}^{2-x}dydx$$

In order to calculate the area, but for some reason I get wrong answer (The answer should be $\frac{3}{2}$).

Any idea how to find the right integral for this area?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Should we be integrating? This is the difference between two easy triangles.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I do understand that we can use the equation of area calculation for trapezoid or use triangles to calculate it, but I'd like to understand how it could be done with integration.

Comment: Draw the picture. For $x>1$, the lower limit for the $y$-integral is $0$, not $1-x$. You'll have to split the double integral into two...

Comment: The limits on your outer integral seem strange (I missed this before). As is, if you replace the lower limit on the inner integral by $0$, you'll have the area of the "triangle on the right". This still leaves you with having to find the area of the "left part": $\int_0^1\int_{1-x}^{2-x} \, dy\,dx$.

Comment: @DavidMitra If I change the outer integral to $\int_0^2$ and leave the inner integral as it is, shouldn't I be able to calculate the integral without spliting it to two? for $x>1$, $y$ is 0 and also 1-x where $x=1$

Comment: No. The region (which I'm assuming is in the first quadrant) is not bounded below by the line $y=1-x$ always. On $[0,1]$, it is, but on $[1,2]$, it's bounded below by the $x$-axis. You could replace the lower limit with an appropriate function, to get one double integral only; but I think that's more trouble than it's worth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A domain $R$ in the $(x,y)$-plane is *$y$-simple* if $R$ can be described as
$$R=\bigl\{(x,y)\>\bigm|\>a\leq x\leq b, \ c(x)\leq y\leq d(x)\bigr\}$$
with given functions $c(\cdot)$ and $d(\cdot)$. For such a domain one has
$$\int_R f(x,y)\>{\rm d}(x,y)=\int_a^b \int_{c(x)}^{d(x)}f(x,y)\>dy\>dx\ ,$$
and in particular
$${\rm area}(R)=\int_a^b\bigl(d(x)-c(x)\bigr)\>dx\ .\tag{1}$$
In your example the function $x\mapsto c(x)$ is not given by a single expression valid for the whole interval $[a,b]$. Therefore you have to split your integral into two parts $\int_0^2=\int_0^1+\int_1^2$.